# Problems with the comparison of two strings using strcmp

Tags: c++, string, comparison, string-comparison, strcmp

I want to compare 2 string but when I do a `strcmp` function, it tells me that:

```
'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string'
```

How can I fix this?

Here is my code :

```
int verif_file(void)
{
    string ligne;
    string ligne_or;

    ifstream verif("rasphone");
    ifstream original("rasphone.pbk");
    while (strcmp(ligne, "[SynCommunity]") != 0 &&
        (getline(verif, ligne) && getline(original, ligne_or)));    
    while (getline(verif, ligne) && getline(original, ligne_or))
    {
        if (strcmp(ligne, ligne_or) != 0)
            return (-1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: what does first `while` loop do? it almost does nothing, right?

Comment: `string` class was precisely introduced to avoid C str functions ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compiler gives you an error because [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) is a C-style function that expects arguments of type `const char*` and there is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `const char*`.

And although you might retrieve a pointer of this type using `std::string`'s `c_str()` method, since you are working with [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects, you should use the ***operator `==`*** instead:

```
if (ligne == ligne_or) ...
```

or comparison with `const char*`:

```
if (ligne == "[Syn****]") ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use `std::string`'s [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp):

```
if (ligne == "[SynCommunity]") ...

if (ligne == ligne_or) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
if (strcmp(ligne, ligne_or) != 0)
```

to

```
if (ligne != ligne_or)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use strcmp, then try

```
if (strcmp(ligne.c_str(), ligne_or.c_str()) != 0)
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the boost algorithm library.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string s1("This is string 1");
std::string s2("this is string 2");

namespace balg = boost::algorithm;

// comparing them with equals
if( balg::equals( s1, s2 ) ) 
     std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
else
     std::cout << "not equal" << std::endl;

// case insensitive  version
if( balg::iequals( s1, s2 ) ) 
     std::cout << "case insensitive equal" << std::endl;
else
     std::cout << "not equal" << std::endl;
```